# Redirect after successful ADB2C login

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using Azure ADB2C authentication in my ASP.NET Core web app.
Based on the claims received after the user logging in, I'd like to redirect the user to another page.

I thought I might be able to redirect the user on the OnTokenValidated event of OpenIdConnectEvents. But frankly, I'm not sure if this is redirecting the client, or redirecting the auth flow. Bottom line, it doesn't redirect the user.

```
public async Task OnTokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context)
{
    // ... clipped code ...


    context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/somewhere");
}
```

My event handler works otherwise--just doesn't redirect.
What is the final event received after a user successfully logs in with ADB2C?
And how, specifically, can I redirect a user?

Thanks

Comment: Did you enable the events? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application-options#support-advanced-scenarios

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Yes, the events are called.